# How to remove letters on strings by using functions with positional arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to remove the specific letters such as "aeiouhwy" from the inputted string by using functions. I've checked the similar questions but I'm not allowed to use list, file or dicitonaries but I can only use loops, functions and conditional statements. In this code below, I don't know where to assign the positional arguments "updated" and "removed". So, I cannot complete my code. Please help!

```
def remove_letters(updated,removed):
    
    new_word = ""
    for i in updated:
        if i not in removed:
            new_word+= i
    return new_word

letters = input("enter a word: ")

new_result = remove_letters(letters)

print(new_result, "aeiouhwy")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "where to assign the positional arguments"? Are you asking how to call the function ``remove_letters``? Are you aware that is the same mechanism as for ``input`` and ``print``.

Comment: I always get this feedback "remove_letters() missing 1 required positional argument: 'removed' ". So, I thought I need to do more with these arguments by adding them  to proper places.

Comment: `new_result = remove_letters(letters)` is missing the letters to remove. `new_result = remove_letters(letters, 'aeiouhwy')`

Comment: @ChrisCharley yes, you are right  I wasn't aware of that thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [8]: removed = "aeiouhwy"
In [12]: def cleaned(word):
    ...:     new_word = ""
    ...:     for i in word:
    ...:         if i not in removed:
    ...:             new_word += i
    ...:     return new_word
    ...:

In [13]: print(cleaned(input("enter a word: ")))
enter a word: aeiunnb
nnb
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using [translate and maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)

```
def remove_letters(sentence, to_remove):
    return sentence.translate(str.maketrans('','',to_remove))

s = 'But for a minister that holds the affairs of the state in the highest regard'

print(remove_letters(s, 'aeiou'))
```

Prints:

```
Bt fr mnstr tht hlds th ffrs f th stt n th hghst rgrd
```